# how to get values from dynamic input field array in php by $_POST when form is submitted?

Tags: php, arrays, input, dynamic, field

```
   i have this input field in my form.

     <input type="text" name="<?=$row['picture_id'] ?>-link[]" id="link" value="<?=$row['link'];?>" size="20" />

$row['picture_id']  is the id coming from database and input field on front end showing value like www.xyz.com .
```

i did print_r($_POST); 
And i am getting....

```
Array ( [539-link] =>Array ( [0] => Array) [450-link] => Array([0]=> Array)) like that but on front end side input field is showing link only like www.xyz.com and www.txy.com

I want to get values of this input field when form is submitted .Form has 'method="post" action="footer_images.php"'.
```

Comment: Please post the full form code.

Comment: what have you tried in order to resolve this yourself?

Comment: `print_r($_POST)`, than rebuild your form as `picture-link[534]`

Comment: jorge costa .....see full form code now. And please help me quick.

Comment: **u_mulder** see full question now and help me quick. how can i get value of this input field in php by $_POST.

Answer (score 0):

You could add like a prefix before the name and that way you can find _POST variables starting with the prefix you set, you can use substr or something to check for that.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" name="<?=$row['picture_id'] ?>-link[]" id="link" value="    <?=$row['link'];?>" size="20" />
//put another input hidden
<input type="hidden" name="pictureId" value="<?=$row['picture_id'];?>" size="20" />
//in footer_images.php
if ( isset($_POST['pictureId']) ){
$id = $_POST['pictureId'] ;
//your value 
if ( isset($_POST[$id.'link']) )
    echo $_POST[$id.'link'];//your value 
}
```

Comment: **leerock leerock**  You are tellig for single input field .and i am asking for array see my input field ..

Comment: **leerock leerock** i did **print_r($_POST);** and i am getting **Array ( [539-link] =>Array ( [0] => Array) [450-link] => Array([0]=> Array))** like that but on front end side input field is showing link only like **www.xyz.com** and **www.txy.com**.